# Django - Save form state

Tags: javascript, python, django, json, forms

I have a form that is completely made of HTML (as opposed to using the django forms). This is because I have several fields that are comboboxes containing foreign key entities and I need to have a "+" button next to each combobox to add new elements.

Hitting the plus button should take me to the form of the entity type in question, and when i add a new element I am taken back to the original form.

Now, I need to save the form state, so that when my user adds the new entity and jumps back to the starting form all the fields that were filled stay filled with the same information.

I'm rather inexperienced with both django and javascript, but from what I found in my research I should be able to pull this off using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse on my forms (gaining a dictionary of the fields and repopulating the form), but I really have no idea how to do this.

My form is consisted of several ordinary text input fields, as well as a few specialized ones for foreign keys:

```
        <tr>
            <td><label for="zbirka">Zbirka: </label></td>
            <td>
                {% if zbirke.count > 0 %}
                <select name="zbirka" id="zbirka">
                    <option value="NONE">...</option>
                    {% for zbirka in zbirke %}
                        {% if zbirka.id == predmet.zbirka.id %}
                            <option value="{{ zbirka.id }}" selected>{{ zbirka.naziv }}</option>
                        {% else %}
                            <option value="{{ zbirka.id }}">{{ zbirka.naziv }}</option>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                {% endif %}
                <button onclick="location.href='/azuriranje/zbirka/dodavanje/?next={{ request.path }}'">+</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Now, I don't have any javascript here, because I tried a few approaches and when I realized that I have no idea what I'm doing I simply reverted back to my first version.

Comment: Could add an example of your HTML and javascript?

Comment: Not sure if this is enough.

Comment: What about making the `+` button `POST` to your server which, in turn, would save the data in your session. The session data would be read on the form view, and written in the `add new element` view.

Comment: The problem is that this whole table row, and all the others are inside a table which is inside a form, and I can't have nested forms.

Comment: Insert their `pk` attributes instead of full data.

Comment: I need both the id, and their name ("naziv") in order to properly display them in the combobox. Furthermore, I'm not even sure what that would change, regarding my problem.

Comment: My point is that the `add new element` form on a separate view would append a `(pk, name)` tuple to a list stored in session. Now, the original form would have that list of tuples passed for `zbirke` variable. And the list would be cleaned on that form's submit.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, so forgive me. I can see how this is more efficient, but not how I can get the form button for `zbirke` inside my primary form for my main model?